# Plot coordinates in ArcGIS 9.3 don't make sense

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, convert, arcgis-9.3, utm

I have a layer of plot features in ArcGIS 9.3 that I want the UTM coordinates for. So I used the Feature to Point tool and then added XY coordinates to each point. I then viewed the Attribute table and noticed the coordinates don't make sense.

Here is the information about my map/projection:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  2000000.00261667
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -79.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    34.33333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    36.16666667
Latitude_Of_Origin: 33.75000000
Linear Unit:    Foot_US

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

I realize the units are in feet (and I ultimately want meters for UTM), so I converted my X and Y to meters by multiplying each value by 0.3048 in an excel spreadsheet.

The resulting units end up in the Pacific Ocean (they're supposed to be in NC in the U.S.).

Examples of my coordinates (from ArcGIS, so they're in feet):

```
X Coord              Y Coord
2008821.00994000000  823231.18663500000
2008796.70771000000  823457.50968900000
```

...converted to meters:

```
X Coord      Y Coord
612288.6438  250920.8657
612281.2365  250989.849
```

**What am I missing here?**

I'm an ArcGIS novice.

Comment: You need to *reproject* to obtain meters in UTM.  Multiplying by 3.something should just shift values into the Atlantic (you seem to have *multiplied* by 0.3...)

Comment: The units are US survey feet, not international foot, so you'd have to divide by 3.28083333333333 instead. As Vince says, you'll want to use the Project Tool to create a new feature class in UTM.

Comment: @mkennedy: Multiplying by 0.3048 and dividing by 3.2808 should give roughly the same values because they are just the inverse of each other.

Comment: Well, yeah, roughly. The inverse of the value I gave is 0.3048006096. When you're working with coordinates that have 6-7 digits to the left of the decimal place, the difference between US survey feet and "international" feet matters. For your eastings, 1.2 meters.

Comment: @mkennedy: that's a fair point, but not the root of my issue. My points are approximately 3500000m too far to the south and 70000m too far to the west

Comment: @Vince: so using the typical foot-to-meter conversion will not suffice? Is a re-projection doing something differently? If so, how do I actually reproject ft to meters?
Also... Is my assumption that the x and y coordinates are in ft even correct??

Comment: UTM and State Plane zones use different projection parameter values, sometimes different map projections (UTM: transverse Mercator), etc. The values look fine to me. By converting them to meters, you've put them into the NAD83 North Carolina state plane coordinate system that uses meters. As I mentioned in my first comment, you need to use the Project Tool and set the output coordsys to NAD 1983 UTM 17N.

Comment: No, unit conversion will not suffice (different projections have different origins as well).  In addition, you described your scaling operation incorrectly ( X1: 2008821 / 0.3048 ~= 6,590,620 )

Comment: Oops. I *multiplied* by 0.3048, not divided. I just wrote the wrong word. I've corrected the wording in my question

Comment: @mkennedy. It seems like you're properly addressing my issue, but I'm not sure I fully understand. Could you either explain a little differently or point me in the direction of where I can read/learn more about what you're describing?

Comment: So if I use the Project Tool, what do I set as my output coordinate system?

Comment: NAD 1983 UTM Zone 17N. It should be under projected coordinate systems, UTM, NAD 1983.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Projections and Transformations > Feature > Project

- Select feature of choice from layers list and drag to "Input Database or Feature Class" field in Project window
- For "Output Coordinate System" field:
  Select > Projected Coordinate Systems > UTM > (projection of choice)

  - (MAKE SURE YOU SELECT THE PROPER ZONE!)

Then I had to open up the Attribute table for my new feature layer and change the x and y point coordinates to meters.

- Right click columns > Calculate Geometry > (select meters)